# Use a chain of filter functions to get 2 complementary sets in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, set

I have a table. I want to select all the rows that meet certain criteria, do something with them, and then do something else with all the other rows. So I need to divide the rows into 2 complementary sets. What's the best (fastest) way to do this?
I think the code below should work, but is there a better solution?

```
var firstSetOfRows = $(".classA");
var allTheOtherRows = $(":not(.classA)");
firstSetOfRows.filter(function() {
        if (decisionFunctionA(this)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            allTheOtherRows.add(this);
            return false;
        }
    }).filter(function() {
        if (decisionFunctionB(this)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            allTheOtherRows.add(this);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Just so you know... `:not(.classA)` selects things like `html`, `head`, `body` and **everything inside those elements** that don't have the class. It doesn't just select the "rows" you speak of.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @BoltClock. I'd started off with `tr.classA` and `tr:not(.classA)`, but then I read that using `tr` would just slow things down. When I debug it, I can see that this works for the positive selection, but as you say, when I use `:not` I end up with a result set 10 x the size as with the correct `tr:not`.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $(".classA").removeClass('SelectedClassA NotSelectedClassA');

        $(".classA").each(function () {
            $(this).addClass(function () {
                return ((decisionFunctionA(this) && decisionFunctionB(this)) ? 'SelectedClassA' : 'NotSelectedClassA');
            });
        });

        $(".classA.SelectedClassA").css({ 'Color': 'red' });
        $(".classA.NotSelectedClassA").css({ 'Color': 'Blue' });
 //Or

    var firstSetOfRows = $(".classA");
    firstSetOfRows.filter(function() {
            if (decisionFunctionA(this) && decisionFunctionB(this)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                allTheOtherRows.add(this);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: can u show me the code for decisionFunctionA(this) && decisionFunctionB(this) ? this two function returning true or false?

Comment: The first function checks whether a particular cell is >= a minimum value, and the second checks whether another cell contains a certain String value. But you're right - I should just call them both from one filter rather than calling them separately from 2 filters.

Answer (score 0):

My initial solution works okay for filter functions (after @BoltClock's `tr` fix), but then I wanted to do the same using selectors in the filter instead of functions. After discovering that `filter()` returns a new JQuery object, leaving the original one unmutated, I've come up with this. (The ps and fs arrays are just for debugging so you can see how many rows have passed or failed at each stage.)

```
function complementaryFilter(originalSet, fltrs, funcPass, funcFail) {
    var passes = $(originalSet), fails = $();
    var ps = [], fs = [];
    for(var i = 0, j = fltrs.length; i < j; i++) {
        fails = fails.add(passes.not(fltrs[i]).get());
        passes = passes.filter(fltrs[i]);
        ps[i] = passes.length;
        fs[i] = fails.length;
    };
    passes.each(funcPass);
    fails.each(funcFail);
}
```

However, this loops over the rows twice - once with `not` to get the failing rows, then again with `filter` to get the passing rows. I'd like to get both in just one pass over the set. (I tried looking at the JQuery source, but it'll take me some time to figure out what's going on in there!)